# bcp sql server devuelve archivo vacio

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo el siguiente store procedure en sql server:

```
USE [Report]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_Traza_OMS]    Script Date: 23/10/2019 9:14:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Traza]
AS
BEGIN       
        SELECT      A.PEDIDO_WEB_LARGO,
                A.FECHA,
                A.FECHA_REVISION,
                1 AS BULTOS,
                C.DocNum AS BOLETA,
                CASE WHEN ISNULL(A.RETIRO_TIENDA,'')='' THEN 'DOMICILIO' ELSE 'RETIRO EN TIENDA' END AS METODO_ENVIO,
                ISNULL(A.RETIRO_TIENDA,'')          AS RETIRO_TIENDA,
                ISNULL(B.carrier,'')                AS TRANSPORTE,
                ISNULL(B.tracking_number,'')        AS TRACKING,
                CASE WHEN  ISNULL(B.carrier,'') = 'CORREOSCHILE' THEN 'https://www.correos.cl/SitePages/seguimiento/seguimiento.aspx?envio='+ISNULL(B.tracking_number,'') ELSE '' END AS LINK,
                ISNULL(D.ESTADO,'')                 AS [ESTADO PEDIDO],
            --  D.ESTADO, 
                ID_MANIFIESTO                       AS [NUMERO MANIFIESTO]
        FROM    WEB A
                LEFT JOIN ENVIAME B     ON A.ID_MOD_WEB = B.ID_MOD_WEB AND B.status_id = 5
                INNER JOIN PAGOS C WITH(NOLOCK)  ON A.OINV = C.Doc 
                LEFT JOIN WEB_RT D  ON A.ID_RT_ESTADO = D.ID_RT_ESTADO
        WHERE   A.FECHA >= '2019-01-01'
                AND     A.ESTADO_REVISION = 1 
                AND     D.ESTADO != '100% Entregado a Cliente' 
                AND     D.ESTADO != 'Cancelado x NC' 

        ORDER BY 1,2,3,4 ASC
END
```

Al cual llamo desde otro sp del que espero obtener un archivo txt o csv con el resultado, sin embargo, al ejecutar el segundo sp éste me devuelve un archivo vacio.  El archivo si se crea en la ruta que he especificado, pero no contiene la información del primer sp.

El segundo sp es el siguiente:

```
DECLARE @Archivo            VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @BCPCMD             NVARCHAR(2000)

DECLARE @NOMBRE VARCHAR(20)
SET @NOMBRE = (CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)+REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),GETDATE(),108),':',''))

SET @Archivo = '\\CS1\Traza\TRAZA_'+@NOMBRE+'.txt'
SET @BCPCMD = 'BCP "EXEC [dbo].[SP_Traza] " queryout "'
    SET @BCPCMD = @BCPCMD + @Archivo + '" -U user -P mypass -c' 
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @BCPCMD, no_output
```

¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Ah, fue un erro de transcripción, ya lo corregí

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que te falta es indicar el servidor al cual se debería conectar el [`BCP`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15), con el parámetro `-S`, ten en cuenta que por más que lo ejecutes desde el propio servidor, debes indicar este dato.

```
SET @BCPCMD = 'BCP "EXEC [dbo].[SP_Traza] " queryout "'
    SET @BCPCMD = @BCPCMD + @Archivo + '" -U user -P mypass -c -S servidor'
```